# xsd to xsd : why i don't suceed to add my tag "balisesXrm" to all my xsd:element?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I'm a new user of XML, stackoverflow saved me on many points but I still got some problems.

I'm trying to transform the following XML schema to add before **all** element a new tag 'balisesXrm' and add the attribute  'maxOccurs' for **each element in a sequence** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsd:complexType name="typeAssociation">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="refid" type="xsd:QName"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType SCCOAMCD:desc="administratif" SCCOAMCD:entite="A-SC.ElementControle" name="ElementControle">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element SCCOAMCD:desc="a_pour_etat" SCCOAMCD:relation="A-SC.ElementControle,EtatEltControle" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="a_pour_etat" type="SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA:EtatEltControle"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType SCCOAMCD:desc="Etat" SCCOAMCD:entite="A-SC.Etat" name="Etat">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element SCCOAMCD:attribut="A-SC.Etat.Commentaires" SCCOAMCD:desc="Commentaires" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="commentaires" type="SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA:typeDatatypeChaine1a2000"/>
        <xsd:element SCCOAMCD:attribut="A-SC.Etat.GdhDebut" SCCOAMCD:desc="Date validité" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="gdhDebut" type="typeDTG"/>
        <xsd:element SCCOAMCD:attribut="A-SC.Etat.GdhFin" SCCOAMCD:desc="retour opé" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="gdhFin" type="typeDTG"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType SCCOAMCD:desc="Description" SCCOAMCD:entite="A-SC.EtatEltControle" name="EtatEltControle">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension SCCOAMCD:entite="A-SC.Etat" base="SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA:Etat">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element SCCOAMCD:attribut="A-SC.EtatEltControle.Etat" SCCOAMCD:desc="controle" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="etat" type="typeString"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA" type="SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA:type_SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

I have writed this xslt :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- Identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- New nodes -->
<xsl:template match="xsd:schema">
    <!-- schema-->
    <xsl:element name="xsd:schema">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:call-template name="lien2"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- création du complexType balisesXrm -->
 <xsl:template name="lien2">
    <xsl:element name="xsd:complexType">
        <xsl:attribute name="name">balisesXrmType</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:element name="xsd:sequence">
                <xsl:element name="xsd:element">
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">balisesXrm:attribut</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="xsd:element">
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">balisesXrm:variable</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="xsd:element">
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">balisesXrm:param</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="xsd:element">
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">balisesXrm:java</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="xsd:element">
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">balisesXrm:historisation-date</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="xsd:any">
                    <xsl:attribute name="minOccurs">0</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element> 
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="xsd:element">
        <xsl:element name="xsd:element">
            <xsl:attribute name="name">balisesXrm</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="type">balisesXrmType</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *"/> 
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- add maxOccurs values unbounded -->
 <xsl:template match="xsd:sequence/xsd:element">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- ... maxOccurs ...-->
        <xsl:attribute name="maxOccurs">unbounded</xsl:attribute>
        <!-- ... copy all-->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()| @*[not(name() = 'maxOccurs')]" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl stylesheet>
```

and i obtain this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<complexType name="typeAssociation">
  <sequence>
     <xsd:element xmlns="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema" xmlns:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema" maxOccurs="unbounded"  name="refid" type="xsd:QName"/>
  </sequence>
  </complexType>

 <complexType SCCOAMCD:desc="administratif" SCCOAMCD:entite="A-SC.ElementControle" name="ElementControle">
    <sequence>
       <xsd:element xmlns="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema" xmlns:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema" maxOccurs="unbounded"  SCCOAMCD:desc="a_pour_etat" SCCOAMCD:relation="A-SC.ElementControle,EtatEltControle" minOccurs="1" name="a_pour_etat" type="SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA:EtatEltControle"/>
    </sequence>
 </complexType>
 <complexType SCCOAMCD:desc="Etat" SCCOAMCD:entite="A-SC.Etat" name="Etat">
    <sequence>
       <xsd:element xmlns="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema" xmlns:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema" maxOccurs="unbounded"  SCCOAMCD:attribut="A-SC.Etat.Commentaires" SCCOAMCD:desc="Commentaires sur l'état" minOccurs="0" name="commentaires" type="SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA:typeDatatypeChaine1a2000"/>
     <xsd:element xmlns="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema" xmlns:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema" maxOccurs="unbounded"  SCCOAMCD:attribut="A-SC.Etat.GdhDebut" SCCOAMCD:desc="Date validité" minOccurs="1" name="gdhDebut" type="typeDTG"/>
     <xsd:element xmlns="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema" xmlns:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema" maxOccurs="unbounded" SCCOAMCD:attribut="A-SC.Etat.GdhFin" SCCOAMCD:desc="retour opé" minOccurs="0" name="gdhFin" type="typeDTG"/>
  </sequence>
 </complexType>

 <complexType SCCOAMCD:desc="Description" SCCOAMCD:entite="A-SC.EtatEltControle" name="EtatEltControle">
    <complexContent>
       <extension SCCOAMCD:entite="A-SC.Etat" base="SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA:Etat">
          <sequence>
             <xsd:element xmlns="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema" xmlns:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema" maxOccurs="unbounded" SCCOAMCD:attribut="A-SC.EtatEltControle.Etat" SCCOAMCD:desc="" minOccurs="1" name="etat" type="typeString"/>
          </sequence>
      </extension>
    </complexContent>
 </complexType>

  <xsd:element name="balisesXrm" type="balisesXrmType"/>
  <xsd:element xmlns="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema" 
xmlns:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA- 
schema" name="SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA" 
type="SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA:type_SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

I don't understand why my tag balisesXrm does not appear in the sequence. However, when I erase the template which add maxOccurs, it works.

When i tried to create only one template for both transformation like this the maxOccurs appear also outside of the sequence : 
    `<xsl:template match="xsd:element">
            <xsl:element name="xsd:element">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">balisesXrm</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="type">balisesXrmType</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="maxOccurs">unbounded</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="ref">attributsXrm</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()| @*[not(name() = 'maxOccurs')]" />
        </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Consider to reduce each problem to a single question with minimal but complete code samples to allow us the exact error description you have. If you have namespace problem then post that in one question, with an exact description of the error/mistake you get. In general, with XSLT, to create result elements, there is no need to use `xsl:element` unless you need to compute the name and/or namespace of an element at run-time. Otherwise you can simply use literal result elements.

Comment: Thank you, i will edit this post and ask for my second problem after.

Comment: It seems you have two templates matching `xsd:element` and in that case only the one with higher priority or in case of the same priority the last one is used. How to solve that depends on the result you want, you might want to edit your question and show us which result you want, you either need to make sure the new element is created matching the sequence or you need to merge the two templates matching an element into one.

Comment: I edit my post explaining i have already tried to merge the two templates. It creates maxOccurs everywhere and I can't have maxOccurs outside sequence without creating an error when i verify my XML document. Anyway, thanks a lot for your patience.

Comment: Do you use an XSLT 2 or 3 processor like Saxon 9 or XmlPrime or Altova? Using `xsl:next-match` might be an option to solve this I think.

Comment: I was using xslt 2, but i post a solution. Thank you for your help and explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it ! I tried this and it works :

```
  <xsl:template match="xsd:element">
         <xsl:element name="xsd:element">
            <xsl:attribute name="name">balisesXrm</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="type">t:balisesXrmType</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:if test="not(parent::xsd:schema)">
            <!-- ... on ajoute les maxOccurs ...-->
            <xsl:attribute name="maxOccurs">unbounded</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <!-- ... on ajoute  l'attributeGroup "attributsXrm" en ref ...-->
        <xsl:attribute name="ref">attributsXrm</xsl:attribute>
        <!-- ... on copie tout en ne touchant pas au maxOccurs (pas besoin de spécifier ref pcq aussi là) -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()| @*[not(name() = 'maxOccurs')]" />
    </xsl:copy>
```